# PHP run jquery/javascript code on another website frontend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url

is it possible to run a specific jquery code on another website frontend.
For example i want to copy some values from specific titles/descipriptions, trigger some click events also and return information as a stored variables in my php file.
Thanks

Comment: Basics of webscraping. Have to find a tool that can load a page and run JavaScript.

Comment: You may go with some scrapping tools or chrome extensions like data miner. You can use it for easy work doing.